# How do I change the alpha value of checkbox with customized image?

Tags: android, checkbox, background, alpha

I want to change the alpha value of the checkbox that in list view. I can change the image for the checkbox. But cannot change the alpha value of it.

layout/list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/col_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/myCheckBox"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/bell_checkbox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/bell_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bell" android:state_checkable="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bell" android:state_checkable="false" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bell" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bell" android:state_checked="false" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bell" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bell" android:state_enabled="false" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bell" />
</selector>
```

The code below works, but not what I want

```
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation (1f, 0.5f); // from 100% visible to 50%
alpha.setDuration (1000); // 1 second, or whatever you want
alpha.setFillAfter(true);
holder.myCheckBox.startAnimation(alpha);
```

I have tried:

```
holder.myCheckBox.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
```

or

```
holder.myCheckBox.getBackground().getCurrent().setAlpha(50);
```

Both cannot change the alpha value.

I think the way that I get the drawable object from my customized checkbox is incorrect:
holder.myCheckBox.getBackground() - It cannot get the drawable object form getBackground() as I set the customized drawable to android:button.

**How can I get the drawable of android:button?**

Can anyone give me some hints?